# Python - Automatically downloading csv files

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make a script that checks [this page](http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/aktier/equities) every minute. Whenever there is a new csv file uploaded to it, I want to download it.

I figured out how to use `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to get the page as follows:

```py
URL = "http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/aktier/equities"

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', 
           "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
           "DNT": "1",
           "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
           "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)  
    if response.status_code == 200:  
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="html.parser")
```

The problem is that I don't know how get the actual file identifiers and how download them.

Looking at the network log of my browser when I download one of the files manually I found references to the file in the following places:

```
**General**  
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=NordicEquity-posttrade-2021-01-15T2144.csv  

**Response headers**  
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=NordicEquity-posttrade-2021-01-15T2144.csv  

**Form Data**  
xmlquery: post>  
param name="SubSystem" value="Prices"/>  
param name="Action" value="GetTrademinute"/>  
param name="Exchange" value="NMF"/>  
param name="trademinute" value="NordicEquity-posttrade-2021-01-15T2144"/>  
param name="assetclass" value="4"/>  
param name="ext_contenttype" value="application/ms-excel"/>  
param name="ext_contenttypefilename" value="NordicEquity-posttrade-2021-01-15T2144.csv"/>  
param name="ext_xslt" value="/nordicV3/trades_csv.xsl"/>  
param name="ext_xslt_lang" value="en"/>  
param name="ext_xslt_hiddenattrs" value=",ins,t,mic,ox,tr,tn,x,oi,sp,at,utcagrt,"/>  
param name="app" value="/aktier/equities"/>  
/post>
```

How can I get the file identifiers and download them?

Comment: Perhaps [`yfinance`](https://algotrading101.com/learn/yfinance-guide/) may help you

Answer (score 0):

After using inspect I found that it's using 'onClick' for the links. In that case, it's better to use selenium(You can install it like [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)). So this is the code for getting the first file on the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/aktier/equities"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/webdriver')
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[(@id = "recordlist")]//a').click()
```